# Pan PictureBox inside a Panel on Mouse Move

Tags: c#, pan

I've a pictureBox1 which is inside Panel1, both of same size. The pictureBox1 is resized on MouseWheel event, when the pictureBox1 size is bigger then Panel1 size then the user can Pan PictureBox1 on Mouse_Move event (want to move with mouse drag, not scroll bars). I've written a code which prevents users to Pan past the Panel1 borders. Right now the code can prevent only Top-Left orner  and Bottom-Right corner. The problem in my code is when the user pans to Top-Right corner or Bottom-Left corner the pictureBox1 is still able to pan. But if pan only one either of one side at a time, the PictureBox1 stays inside the Panel1.
I tried editing my code but I'm not able to get a proper solution. if anyone can help me figure out this problem in my code will be a great help.

The below code is under `pictureBox1_MouseMove` event

Top-Left Corner
[image: Top Left Corner]

Bottom-Right Corner
[image: Bottom Right Corner]

Top-Right Corner
[image: Top Right Corner]

Bottom-Left Corner
[image: Bottom Left Corner]

```
    if (pictureBox1.Width > panel1.Width || pictureBox1.Height > panel1.Height)
{
    int count = 0;  // Counter to check Top-Left points, if crossed panel's (0,0) points
                    // If count = 1, Set pictureBox point X or Y to 0.
                    // If count = 2, Set both the points of pictureBox to (0,0)
    int count2 = 0; // Counter to check Bottom-Right points, if crossed Panels negative values calculated by panel1.Width-pictureBox1.Width
                    // If count2 = 1, Set pictureBox point X or Y to minPointX or minPointY .
                    // If count2 = 2, Set both the points of pictureBox to (minPointX, minPointY )

    int minPointX = panel1.Width - pictureBox1.Width;
    int minPointY = panel1.Height - pictureBox1.Height;
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Calculation for Left Top corner.
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if ((e.X - startPoint.X) >= 0 && pictureBox1.Location.X >= 0)
    {
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(0, pictureBox1.Location.Y);
        count++;
    }
    if((e.Y - startPoint.Y) >= 0 && pictureBox1.Location.Y >= 0)
    {
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X, 0);
        count++;
    }
    if (count == 1)
    {
        if(pictureBox1.Location.X == 0)
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(0, pictureBox1.Location.Y + e.Y - startPoint.Y);
        if( pictureBox1.Location.Y == 0)
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X + e.X - startPoint.X, 0);
    }
    if (count == 2)
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Calculation for Bottom Right corner.
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if((e.X - startPoint.X) <= 0 && pictureBox1.Location.X <= minPointX)
    {
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(minPointX, pictureBox1.Location.Y);
        count2++;
    }
    if((e.Y - startPoint.Y) <= 0 && pictureBox1.Location.Y <= minPointY)
    {
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X, minPointY);
        count2++;
    }
    if(count2 == 1)
    {
        if (pictureBox1.Location.X == minPointX)
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(minPointX, pictureBox1.Location.Y + e.Y - startPoint.Y);
        if (pictureBox1.Location.Y == minPointY)
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X + e.X - startPoint.X, minPointY);
    }
    if (count2 == 2)
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(minPointX, minPointY);
    if (count == 0 && count2 == 0)
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X + e.X - startPoint.X, pictureBox1.Location.Y + e.Y - startPoint.Y);
}
```

The Current code stops the user to move the pictureBox Beyond Point(0,0) on Top-Left Corner if the user tries to move the pictureBox towards right-down, and Beyond Point(minPointX, minPointY) if the user tries to move the pictureBox towards top-right.
`minPointX` and `minPointY` is calculated by substracting the `panel.Width` to `pictureBox.Width` and `panel.Heigh` to `pictureBox.Height` respectively. minPointX and minPointY are the minimum points to which a user can move the pictureBox towards negative x and y axis.

Comment: if you just want to allow the user to move the picturebox inside the panel, then why don't you set the AutoSrcoll property of the panel? it will create scrollbars to allow to move the inner control (pan it).

Comment: I don't want to use scroll bars. I want to pan it on Mouse move event.

Comment: You can change the HorizontalScroll.Value and VerticalScroll.Value to move the content with the delta of the mouse movement, in this way you will give the user two methods to pan the content.

Comment: Lol gave down vote and left no comment. that was a great help huh

Comment: One first tip: use helpful names. does `count` actually count anything? What?? Also: where is the code located and what is the goal it has? MouseMove???

Comment: ok ill edit it now. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the panel `autoScroll` property. Make sure the `pictureBox` inside the panel is not anchored. Then set panel `autoScroll` property to `true`.

Now when the `pictureBox` gets bigger then the panel it will automatically show the Scroll bars.
Now in the mouse move event set the `AutoScrollPosition` as shown in the below code. Hope it helps.
In the code below e is the `MouseEventArgs`.

```
panel1.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(-(panel1.AutoScrollPosition.X + e.X - startPoint.X),
                                      -(panel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y + e.Y - startPoint.Y));
```

Comment: OP has clearly stated that he doesn't want scrollbars. Can you hide them?

Comment: oh. No cannot hide scrollbars when auto scroll is set to true.

Comment: I'll bet you probably *can* figure out a way to hide the scrollbars. But even if you could, I would strongly advise against it. Scrollbars both make it clear that the area is movable, and provide an alternative way of scrolling for users who can't or don't want to pan with the mouse. Drag-panning is a great option that should be supported for convenience, but it should not be the *only* option. Just like touch. Unless you're writing for hardware that has a built-in touch screen and no other viable means of interaction, you should support multiple paradigms. Nothing wrong with scrollbars.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a routine that contrains a control to stay within a viewport. It assumes that both dimensions are larger than the viewport..

```
void constrain(Control ctl, Control view)
{
    Rectangle pr = view.ClientRectangle;
    Rectangle cr = ctl.ClientRectangle;

    int x = Math.Min(0, Math.Max(ctl.Left, pr.Width - cr.Width));
    int y = Math.Min(0, Math.Max(ctl.Top, pr.Height - cr.Height));

    ctl.Location = new Point(x,y);
}
```